# Are there any prepaid travel cards available in Japanese Yen?

Tags: international-travel, japan, money, payment-cards, forex-cards

Are there any prepaid travel cards (like the *[Amex GlobalTravel](https://www.americanexpress.com/us/content/prepaid/global-travel-card.html)*) available in Japanese Yen?

Comment: Where are you based? It seems like every major bank in Australia offers cash cards that support JPY but I'm having more trouble finding international vendors.

Comment: I can get from Brazil or USA.

Comment: What is a "travel card"? Some kind of ticket? Your question will be improved by briefly telling us.

Comment: If that's a pre-paid credit card, I would suggest not using them in Japan. Credit cards are becoming more accepted here, but Japan is still largely a cash based society. Big chain stores and restaurants take them and many taxis. But there are many chain stores that DON'T accept CC yet. My local grocery store is a chain store and it doesn't accept credit cards. Your best bet is to buy traveler's checks and get them exchanged at the airport when you arrive or at a bank.

Comment: I will suggest just carrying some cash. Don't worry about theft; it doesn't really happen in Japan if you take the very basic precautions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Travelex](http://www.travelex.com) offers cash passports:

> You can choose to pick up your currency in one of our many stores or
>   have it delivered directly to your door.

It covers many of the major currencies, including Japanese YEN.

[Cash Passports with Travelex](http://www.travelex.com/US/Products/Cash-Passport/)

You can buy at their counters in most major international airports, or online in advance.

Comment: Just an update: Travelex no longer seems to be selling Cash Passorts inside the US.

Comment: And you can get a better exchange rate than Travelex from many places.

Answer (score 2):

From [Finder](https://www.finder.com/uk/travel-money/japan)

Japan is very much like a cash society. Hotel and travel bookings, as well as big-ticket items, should be purchased on your credit card and if possible make the most of your card's interest-free days feature.

You need to be wary of travel cards, compare the exchange rate on offer from your travel card issuer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated Japan is a cash society, and many places do not accept credit cards.  There are cash exchange locations at the airports that are operated by banks which offer better rates than Travelex.  I've have had good luck getting cash from post office ATMs, and 7-11 stores.

For convenience I do recommend getting an IC card.  SUICA and PASMO are the 2 major ones, and they can be recharged at most train/subway stations.  The money on the card can be used for travel, vending machines, some lockers, and many stores.  It keep you from having a pocket full of change.  Super handy.

https://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pass/suica.html
https://www.pasmo.co.jp/visitors/en/normalpasmo/